# How do I add an array as another array's children, recursively?

Tags: php, recursion, multidimensional-array, laravel-7, array-push

I need to build a tree of objects with parent/child relationship. My objects have a parent_id.

```
public function index()
{
    $root = Project::find($_POST['project_id']);
    $tree = array('name' => $root->name, 'children' => array());
    $this->addChildren($tree, 0, $root->id);
    return response()->json(json_encode($tree));
}
```

I call a recursive function *addChildren()* to build the tree hierarchy from the relational database.

```
private function addChildren($object, $parent_id, $project_id)
{
    $criterias = Criteria::where([['project_id', '=', $project_id], ['parent_id', '=', $parent_id]])->get();
    foreach($criterias as $criteria) {
        $item = array('name' => $criteria->name, 'children' => array());
        array_push($object['children'], $item);
        if($criteria->has_child)
            $this->addChildren($item, $criteria->id, $criteria->project_id);
    }    
}
```

However, when I run this, the **$tree** object returns empty from all but the inital push made to it outside of the recursive *addChildren()* function :
`{name: "Test Project", children: Array(0)}`.

I have tried pushing to *$object['children']* with both

> `array_push($object['children'], $item);`

and

> `$object['children'][] = $item;`

with the same outcome.

I know that the database calls are working fine because, in the Laravel debugbar, I can see that the queries made to the database match all the id's that should be returned.

Comment: You need to return something: `return $this->addChildren(...)` otherwise the recursion will not have an updated value to work with.

Comment: Could you provide a short example? I have tried returning the function call with no success.

Comment: `$tree = $this->addChildren($tree, 0, $root->id);` .. then use `return` in your function. Recursion is a cool way to do things in your application, I guess you can find some tutorials to understand how it works.

Answer (score 0):

I fixed with the help of Felippe Duarte's comment. Adding a return value to the function and setting that value to the array did the trick.

`$tree['children'] = $this->addChildren(0, $root->id);`

and

```
private function addChildren($parent_id, $project_id)
{
    $criterias = Criteria::where([['project_id', '=', $project_id], ['parent_id', '=', $parent_id]])->get();
    $children = [];
    foreach($criterias as $criteria) {
        $item = array('name' => $criteria->name, 'children' => array());            
        if($criteria->has_child) {
            $item['children'] = $this->addChildren($criteria->id, $criteria->project_id);    
        }
        array_push($children, $item);        
    }
    return $children;
}
```